# How to prevent input from starting a new line in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, my code is like

```
a = input('a is: ')
b = input('b is: ')
```

I hope the running result is

```
a is: test1
b is: test2
```

but actually the result is

```
a is: test1

b is: test2
```

This is awfully ugly as for me.
Can anyone offer a simple solution to this?

Comment: Tried the same code and it doesn't behave the same in the Linux Terminal.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I enter a value for the first call to `input`, the prompt from the second call to `input` is displayed one newline below the first.

Comment: Oops, it does occur in my Spyder, but it's not a problem when i use cmd to run the program!

Comment: OK, this seems to be a bug of Spyder and it's not fixed yet, thank you guys all the same